# Disable session in Express app config

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using Express with Passport for an Node.js API app, and I can disable sessions by passing `{session:false}` to `passport.authenticate`, but is there a way I can do this in one place so I don't repeat myself 600 times?

```
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
});

app.get('/users', passport.authenticate('hash', {session:false}), controllers.users.getAll);
app.get('/users/me', passport.authenticate('hash', {session:false}), controllers.users.getCurrentUser);
// and so on...
```

It would be great if I could just do:

```
app.donotuse(sessions).thanks();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just save the result in a variable and re-use it:

```
var PassportAuthenticateMiddleware = passport.authenticate('hash', {session:false});
...
app.get('/users',    PassportAuthenticateMiddleware, controllers.users.getAll);
app.get('/users/me', PassportAuthenticateMiddleware, controllers.users.getCurrentUser);
```

(or do as @hexacyanide suggests and use the middleware globally, if that's an option in your setup)

Alternatively, you can use something similar to this:

```
app.all('/users*',   passport.authenticate('hash', {session:false}));
app.get('/users',    controllers.users.getAll);
app.get('/users/me', controllers.users.getCurrentUser);
```

This will filter all requests (instead of `.all` you can use `.get` too) whose URL starts with `/users` to be run through the authentication middleware.

Comment: This makes sense, and what @hexacyanide suggested is what I was looking for, though @Krasimir's answer does make me think. Certain route such as `/login` will need to be anonymous. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @AdamKDean for the routes that don't need the middleware, just don't use it in the route declaration :) `app.get('/login', controllers.users.login)`

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Just what I was looking for, and the wildcards too, awesome. Thanks again Robert!

Answer (score 3):

The authenticator itself is middleware. Therefore, you can assign it globally.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.authenticate('hash', {session:false}));
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, though I have to ask, how would you bypass this for certain routes you wanted to be anonymous?

Comment: ^^ use this with the express-unless package

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have some routes which need session. It is possible to set this globally, but this will not work in your case. What you can do is to improve the code a bit:

```
var controller = function(controller) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('hash', {session:false})(req, res, next);
        controller(req, res, next);
    }
}
app.get('/users', controller(controllers.users.getAll));
app.get('/users/me', controller(controllers.users.getCurrentUser));
```

Comment: That's not going to do the same, since you're setting up the authenticate middleware and the controller to be called independently of each other.